# JS onkeydown/onkeyup - convert to jQuery keydown/keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have some js for phone number validation that is using inline event listeners in the input field. I need to change this example so that instead of attaching the event listeners inline, I would be targeting the DOM element in jQuery and adding the event listeners. Here's a working example of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/21/

```
window.mask = function (e,f){
    var len = f.value.length;
    var key = whichKey(e);
    if((key>=47 && key<=58) || (key>=96 && key<=105))
    {
        if( len==1 )f.value='('+f.value
        else if(len==4 )f.value=f.value+')'
        else if(len==8 )f.value=f.value+'-'
        else f.value=f.value;
    }
}

function whichKey(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    return code
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onkeydown="mask(event,this)" onkeyup="mask(event,this)" maxlength="13" />
```

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/25/) but was unable to achieve the functionality that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have update you jsfiddle example:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#edit-phone1').keyup(function(event){
        mask(event,this);
    });
    jQuery('#edit-phone1').keydown(function(event){
        mask(event,this);
    });
});
```

click here to see working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/38/

or you can try :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-phone1').on("keyup keydown", function(e) {
        mask(e, this);
    });

});
```

link for this is:-http://jsfiddle.net/yVdgL/56/

Comment: Answer is still wrong...Not sure how it is selected as the correct solution! I guess you do not use Firefox. event is not defined. See my solution on how to define event.

Comment: congrats, now your answer matches mine ;) Hopefully the OP checks and sees there was a change. lol

Answer (score 0):

In older, pre-HTML5 browsers, `$("#phone").keyup( function )` or `keydown` is definitely what you're looking for.

In HTML5 there is a new event, "input", which behaves exactly like you seem to think "change" should have behaved - in that it fires as soon as a key is pressed to enter information into a form. `$("#phone").bind('input',function)`;

Answer (score 0):

You never defined event.

```
jQuery('#edit-phone1').keyup(function(){
    jQuery('#edit-phone1').mask(event,this);  //<-- what is event?
});
```

just add it

Second issue is you are treating window.mask like a jQuery plugin and it is not a plugin.

```
jQuery('#edit-phone1').keyup(function(event){  //<-- add event here
    mask(event,this);  
});
```

Comment: I should also note that whichKey method is not needed since jQuery normalizes it. You can just use which or keyCode.